# Como puedo imprimir los resultados y hacer gráficos de esta clase basada en un archivo JSON?

Tags: python, json, visual-studio, matplotlib, jupyter

Tengo está Tabla generada a través de una API:

```
import requests
import json
import math
data_list= requests.get(url='https://randomuser.me/api')
data_list.json()
```

La impresión es la siguiente:

La API genera 5000 registros aleatorios, ahora lo que necesito es sacar estadísticas y gráficos con esa API, se generaron las siguientes clases:

```
class Name:
    def __init__(self, name_data):
        self.title = name_data["title"]
        self.first = name_data["first"]
        self.last = name_data["last"]
```

### Necesito ayuda para poder imprimir datos y generar gráficos estadísticos, no se como imprimir cada clase, ya que estoy aprendiendo recien Python y nos dieron un trabajo muy complicado.
Alguna sugerencia para poder hacer este trabajo, les agradeceria mucho su aporte gracias.